# GRPC reconnection and keep the connection

Tags: java, stream, connection, grpc, observers

```
StreamObserver<RouteSummary> responseObserver = new StreamObserver<RouteSummary>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(RouteSummary summary) {
                LOGGER.info("Action.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                LOGGER.error("Error.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                LOGGER.info("Completed.");
            }
        };
```

There is a grpc connection and client side streaming. Its started but If the Grpc Client is restarted,
how can I keep getting responses where they left off.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side streaming means request streaming. Assuming you meant server side streaming, if the client is restarted it has basically lost the messages in the previous response stream.

Comment: How can I go on taking responses.

Comment: If the client restarts you will have to make a new request to get responses.